# Convert HTML with CDN Libraries and External stylesheets to PDF

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, jspdf

[image]I designed my resume with bootstrap and material design lite, now I want to convert the html page to pdf file.

I tried some libraries (jsPdf) and some tools (html2pdf, princexml), it produces the pdf file but the problem is, that pdf is not what it looks in the html page.

There is no styles, the output i am getting is similar to pressing ctrl+p` in browser.

My question is, 
**Is there any tools or libraries for my problem ?** 
or 
**Is there any options in above mentioned tools that i can use?**

pdf outputs[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's wrong with Ctrl+P?

Comment: Yeah shouldn't Ctrl-P include styling?

Comment: There was no styles in the output pdf when i pressed ctrl+p

Answer (score 1):

Try this converter [WKHTMLTOPDF](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) on your back-end. It outputs exactly what your see in you browser. It supports html, css and even js. Wkhtmltopdf based on webkit.

Using runtime it can be used like that

```
wkhtmltopdf http://google.com google.pdf
```

In your case, it seems that wkhtmltopdf can not load css. Check right css include path. Do not use relative path.

Comment: I tried, but same output. is there a way to include external files. I tried this it didn't work.                                                                                  wkhtmltopdf --user-style-sheet http://localhost/cv/MaterialCV1/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css --user-style-sheet http://localhost/cv/MaterialCV1/bower_components/material-design-lite/material.css --user-style-sheet http://localhost/cv/MaterialCV1/styles/main.css --run-script http://localhost/cv/MaterialCV1/bower_components/material-design-lite/material.js http://localhost/cv/MaterialCV1/ final.pdf

Comment: What backend do you use?

Comment: I run it on apache httpd server but there is nothing in the backend

Comment: Can you provide some example? Before - After

Comment: Seems that wkhtmltopdf can not load css. Check right css include path. Do not use relative path.
Please show style including part of html.

Comment: Try to run wkhtmltopdf using https://github.com/Rademade/wkhtmltopdf_online_client

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the Bootstrap library, not any plugins or PDF tools you are using. It removes most styles when you "print" a web page, including print to PDF. My company, the DocRaptor HTML to PDF service, has a [great blog post](https://docraptor.com/blog/making-pdfs-with-bootstrap/) with a list of suggested fixes for getting Bootstrap styles to print correctly, but they could be summarized as:

- Print using screen CSS mode/rules, not print. Otherwise, you have to a lot of overrides for Bootstrap to get it to work right. Much easier to just make the renderer use screen mode.
- Bootstrap will think most PDFs are an extra small device, like a cell phone, so you have to either adjust your breakpoints or your in-code column definitions.
- If your last column drops to a new row, this is because Bootstrap defines the width for many columns as XX.66666667%. The PDF engine adds all these up, and because of the 7 at the end, it is technically greater than 100%. Since the row width is over 100%, it bumps the last column to a new row. the fix is to override Bootstrap's column widths ([handy Gist file for that](https://gist.github.com/JamesPaden/e7e3752b644c271ce600)).

Answer (score 0):

**jsPDF is able to use plugins.** In order to enable it to print HTML, you have to include certain plugins and therefore have to do the following:

1. Go to https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF and download the latest Version.
2. Include the following Scripts in your project:

   - jspdf.js
   - jspdf.plugin.from_html.js
   - jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js
   - jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js

If you want to ignore certain elements, you have to mark them with an ID, which you can then ignore in a special element handler of jsPDF. Therefore your HTML should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="ignorePDF">don't print this to pdf</p>
    <div>
      <p><font size="3" color="red">print this to pdf</font></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then you use the following JavaScript code to open the created PDF in a PopUp:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();          
var elementHandler = {
  '#ignorePDF': function (element, renderer) {
    return true;
  }
};
var source = window.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
doc.fromHTML(
    source,
    15,
    15,
    {
      'width': 180,'elementHandlers': elementHandler
    });

doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
```

For me this created a nice and tidy PDF that only included the line 'print this to pdf'.

Please note that the special element handlers only deal with IDs in the current version, which is also stated in a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/34). It states:

> Because the matching is done against every element in the node tree, my desire was to make it as fast as possible. In that case, it meant "Only element IDs are matched" The element IDs are still done in jQuery style "#id", but it does not mean that all jQuery selectors are supported.

Therefore replacing '#ignorePDF' with class selectors like '.ignorePDF' did not work for me. Instead you will have to add the same handler for each and every element, which you want to ignore like:

```
var elementHandler = {
  '#ignoreElement': function (element, renderer) {
    return true;
  },
  '#anotherIdToBeIgnored': function (element, renderer) {
    return true;
  }
};
```

From the [examples](http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/examples/basic.html) it is also stated that it is possible to select tags like 'a' or 'li'. That might be a little bit to unrestrictive for the most usecases though:

> We support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style
>   ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
>   There is no support for any other type of selectors (class, of
>   compound) at this time.

**One very important thing to add is that you lose all your style information (CSS). Luckily jsPDF is able to nicely format h1, h2, h3 etc., which was enough for my purposes. Additionalyl it will only print text within text nodes, which means that it will not print the values of textareas and the like. Example:**

```
<body>
  <ul>
    <!-- This is printed as the element contains a textnode -->        
    <li>Print me!</li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <!-- This is not printed because jsPDF doesn't deal with the value attribute -->
    <input type="textarea" value="Please print me, too!">
  </div>
</body>
```